# DocuSign: Multiple documents and templates in one envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Using the **DocuSign API**, is it possible to send multiple documents with multiple (predefined) templates - in one envelope?

For example, one envelope would include the following:

- ***Document name*** => ***Template ID***
- document-one.docx => "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
- document-two.docx => "EEEE-FFFF-GGGG-HHHH"

I then need to add multiple recipients, matched to the template by the recipient's role.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you've described is possible -- by using **Composite Templates** in the **Create Envelope** API request.  For details, see DocuSign's API documentation (specifically, the **Composite Templates** section of [this page](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/)). For additional examples, I'd suggest you search the **docusignapi** tag here on Stack Overflow for "composite templates" -- you'll find lots of questions/answers that contain relevant code snippets.

Comment: I've read some of your posts elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19308660/4483618), but I can't see a clear example of providing a server template ID and associating it with a document provided in the API request.

Would this request work: https://gist.github.com/benrolfe/1787a6476cb0972c3b2da617fc8d251d